# PHP displaying $_POST values as "1" and not element values

Tags: php, html, post

Why are my values not being read by php?

```
One Color <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="oneColor" value="oneColor" checked/><br>
Two Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="twoColor" value="twoColor"/><br>
Three Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="threeColor" value="threeColor"/><br>
Four Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="fourColor" value="fourColor"/><br>
Five Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="fiveColor" value="fiveColor"/><br><br>
```

Here's my php $_POST variable.

```
$numberOfColors = isset($_POST["NumberOfColors"]);
```

My main problem though is that php returns a "1" and not the actual value from the html element. So if oneColor was checked it just returns a "1" instead of "oneColor." I've tried just using integers for the value but it still doesn't work. Is there something that I need to change in the php.ini file?

I'm also having this problem with some check boxes, but those aren't as important in the program.

Comment: First of all read what is the return value of `isset`

Comment: If I asked you `is this variable set` what would you expect as an answer? Yes, No or 42?

Comment: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) `bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns a boolean: true or false. Which when printed becomes 1 or 0.

Try this:

```
// if $_POST["NumberOfColors"] is true give its value else give 0
$numberOfColors = isset($_POST["NumberOfColors"]) ? $_POST["NumberOfColors"] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is set first, then assign to variable. Isset is boolean.

```
If (isset($_POST["NumberOfColors"])) {
    $numberOfColors = $_POST["NumberOfColors"];
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. _And maybe upvoting it if its good_

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML code

```
One Color <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" <?php if (isset($NumberOfColors) && $NumberOfColors=="oneColor") echo "checked";?> id="oneColor" value="oneColor"><br>
Two Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" <?php if (isset($NumberOfColors) && $NumberOfColors=="twoColor") echo "checked";?> id="twoColor" value="twoColor"/><br>
Three Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" <?php if (isset($NumberOfColors) && $NumberOfColors=="threeColor") echo "checked";?> id="threeColor" value="threeColor"/><br>
Four Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" <?php if (isset($NumberOfColors) && $NumberOfColors=="fourColor") echo "checked";?> id="fourColor" value="fourColor"/><br>
Five Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" <?php if (isset($NumberOfColors) && $NumberOfColors=="fiveColor") echo "checked";?> id="fiveColor" value="fiveColor"/><br><br>
```

PHP
By adding some submit button you can do PHP like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $NumberOfColors = $_POST['NumberOfColors'];
}
```

It works for me. I hope it will help you

Comment: Why downvote.? Can anyone explain?

Comment: You are not answering the question. He is not interested in se-setting the button that was selected last time the form was submitted so you are just confusing the issue by adding that code

Comment: His code was not working. I have also faced that problem and tackled that by this code

Comment: For reference you can see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Comment: PS: One of your radio buttons will have 2 `checked` attributes? Woops and likely in some case 2 radio buttons will have the `checked` attribute set BIG Woops

Comment: Ok. I have corrected it. Basically it was for by default checked. I have gone through this code. If you dont do that then all of the radio buttons remain unchecked by default

Comment: It had no problem with php. However I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You are using a radio button set

```
One Color <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="oneColor" value="oneColor" checked/><br>
Two Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="twoColor" value="twoColor"/><br>
Three Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="threeColor" value="threeColor"/><br>
Four Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="fourColor" value="fourColor"/><br>
Five Colors <input type="radio" name="NumberOfColors" id="fiveColor" value="fiveColor"/><br><br>
```

A radio button set has the same name attribute `name="NumberOfColors"` in your case.

Only one value can be returned from a radio button set and that value will be the value in the `value="fiveColor"` attribute of the ONE button that was set.

So when processing a radio button set you must first check that something was selected and then capture the value so you know which option was selected

```
// was any of my radion buttons selected
if ( isset($_POST["NumberOfColors"]) {
    // this one was selected
    $theSelected = $_POST["NumberOfColors"];
}
```

Comment: [*Can I get an "arumph"?!*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056329/php-displaying-post-values-as-1-and-not-element-values#comment65462013_39056329)

Comment: I take it you've seen the OP's (bad) track record. Doubting a green medal anywhere.